# qemu-kvm on centos: how to get back vmvga?

Tags: centos, qemu, linux-kvm, centos-8

I am currently using qemu-kvm (reports version QEMU emulator version 4.2.0 (qemu-kvm-4.2.0-59.module_el8.5.0+1063+c9b9feff.1)) as virtualization engine.

My guest is an old SLES instance with 2.4smp kernel. I do not want to change the guest or its kernel. I know that my guest supports vmvga just fine, however I cannot select it, as it has been removed from the standard Centos version of qemu. See also here: https://www.mail-archive.com/qemu-discuss@nongnu.org/msg06708.html

Cirrus is limiting my resolution in the guest to 1152x768, however I'd like to get full-hd. As the guest is too old for any of the newer graphics types I am looking for a way to get back the vmvga graphics mode in Centos8. In the ideal case it can be re-activated or added to my current setup. However, if necessary I'd also be interested in the way to remove the default centos packages where this adapter is disabled and install "default" ones with this type still supported.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it on my own. As I had quite some uncertainties though, I am only gonna write down the high-level steps:

1. Update qemu-kvm from v4.2 which is the default in Centos 8.5 to 7.0 using the ravens-extras repository
   -> I had lot's of difficulties here, as the newer versions weren't recognized as updates, so I worked with dnf install and the --allowerase switch
2. I had to upgrade to Centos 8 Stream to fulfill an selinux dependency (even though I have selinux disabled on my system)
3. Finally qemu-kvm accepted the vmvga entry, however it complained about a missing file called vgabios-vmware.bin
   Solution is to go to https://github.com/qemu/vgabios and build it manually. I then did $ sudo cp VGABIOS-lgpl-latest.vmware.bin /usr/share/seavgabios/vgabios-vmware.bin and finally the machine started!

As expected I can now get full-screen resolution!

A lot of trouble for this. I wish the adapter hadn't been removed in the first place...